# Path must include project and resource name / error

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I have checked out a maven project in eclipse using the option:

```
Import > Maven > Check out Maven Projects from SCM
```

When I try to build the project using:

```
Project > Clean
```

I get the following errors:

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2163)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFolder(Container.java:222)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:178)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.mavenProjectChanged(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.notifyProjectChangeListeners(ProjectRegistryManager.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.applyMutableProjectRegistry(ProjectRegistryManager.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenProjectManager.refresh(MavenProjectManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_17
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

I can't see any problems with the configuration. Other people have checked out this project without this error. I don't know what it is referring to when it says 'Path must include...' where can I configure this path?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the project in Eclipse and selecting Maven > Update Dependencies and selecting all projects?

Comment: It's not a single project, it checks out as 4 separate java projects. I tried right clicking on one of them, and selecting 'Maven'. I don't have an `Update Dependencies` option under 'Maven', I just have 'Update Project'. When I do `Update Project` I get the same error

Comment: Its hard to tell without looking but sounds like there is a problem with checking out the 4 separate projects - you need to have a root project as well, have you checked this out? If other people have successfully checked this out then you must have done something different so try to compare your workspace with theirs

Comment: Another team member now has the same problem. Only one person on the team has managed to import the GIT project properly. It seems to have trouble with the fact that the build output directory is outside the project. On the machine that it works properly on, it creates a folder with an environment variable: ${env.BROOT}. So, it seems to have picked up that the project is building to an external directory. This also works on Windows, it inserts the external folder. We have compared two identical installations built from a CentOS VM, and we cannot see any difference between the two versions.

Comment: yes, we have a root project

Comment: This error actually occurs when the project is being imported, even before it is built.

Comment: @maloney you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by locally defined environment variable called $BROOT which was set in ~/.bashrc, and then picked up by the maven pom.xml. The environment variable put the output directory of the project outside the eclipse workspace, which is not how Eclipse likes to do things.

The solution was to unset the environment variable. This is the reason it works in Windows because Windows wouldn't know anything about ~/.bashrc.

Comment: And that environmental variable would be... ?

Comment: Added environment variable name to the answer

Comment: Just FYI: the real reason of your problem was that `Eclipse JDT` does not allow setting output dir outside of the project. So if you've had the variable pointing out somewhere outside, it violated Eclipse rules.

Comment: Thanks @G.Demecki, you solved my issue (deployment assembly pointing to some weird places like ".").