# 'Android Pre Compiler' error 'Path must include project and resource name'

Tags: android, eclipse, git, adt, precompile

I'm trying to compile the Android project [SGTPuzzles](http://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles), and am running into problems that I need help understanding. The error is:

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'SGTPuzzles'.
>   Path must include project and resource name: /SGTPuzzles

I'm new to Android development (and Eclipse and Java), and so I'm not really sure how to figure out the source of the error. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, ADT v22.3, and have imported the SGTPuzzles project into my Eclipse workspace with the included Git tools.

I searched the web and found similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635526/path-must-include-project-and-resource-name-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418322/eclipse-adt-build-error) (among some less useful non-stackoverflow results), but no solutions. I've tried clearing my workspace, re-cloning the repository, and restarting Eclipse. I've tried the 'Android Tools'->'Fix Project Properties'. Nothing has helped. I don't know where to look to learn more about what file or resource is causing this problem, so it's tricky for me to debug. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am able to build with ant successfully, so this is Eclipse specific. Some more comments here (https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/issues/62) and here (https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/pull/78).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's my fault: I had the `*.c` files at the root of the project (hoping to keep the same paths as upstream svn), and thus the root as a source folder, and ADT started objecting to that, by crashing in `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.SourceProcessor.buildSourceFileList()` trying to resolve `/SGTPuzzles` to a project **and resource** (i.e. subfolder), which fails. Fixed in current git by `mv *.c jni/`.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Out of curiosity, did you have to dig around to figure that out, or did the error message direct you straight to the problem? I ask because it'd be really helpful if I could debug this kind of problem on my own in the future, and don't yet have the experience with Android that I needed to figure it out. How did you figure this out?

Comment: @MichaelRepucci Eclipse has Window/Show view/Error log, where you can double click for a stack trace. The ADT source is public (e.g. android.googlesource.com) and the line the trace indicated in SourceProcessor crucially hinted that the folder mentioned was a source folder. Lines further in showed that that was not allowed to be the root.

Answer (score 19):

This helped me:

- Right click on the project and go to "Properties"
- Select "Java Build Path" on the left
- Open "Source" tab
- Remove "YourProject" from source files (make sure "gen" folder and "src" are in the source files)
- Again right click on the project and in the "Andriod Tools" click on "Fix Project Properties"

Comment: This helped me solve the problem after creating the project. But is there a way to solve this while creating a new project? I get this every time I create a new project and thus there is no auto generated code :(